# Stationary distribution of a Memoryless 2-type priority queue

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I have come across the following priority queue, which seems quite natural to me.

A single queue with 2 types of costumers, independent Poisson arrivals and Poisson services.

First class costumers arrive according to a Poisson process with rate a1.
Second class costumers arrive according to a Poisson process with rate a2.
Service process is again a Poisson process, with rate 1.
All three processes are independent.  a1+a2<1.
At each service time, if there is a 1st class costumer in the queue, it is immediately served and leave the queue. If no 1st class costumer is in the queue, it is offered to a 2nd class costumer. If the queue is empty the service does nothing.
Let Q1 denote the number of 1st class costumers in the queue and Q2 denote the #of 2nd class costumers. (Q1,Q2) is a Markov chain and when a1+a2<1 it is positive recurrent.

**I am interested in understanding the stationary distribution of (Q1,Q2)**

Surprisingly enough, I could not find anything in the literature, and did not manage to solve this myself.
I would be happy for a solution, for some references, or to know if this has been considered before (and if this is considered hard).

A few remarks:
It is classical that if one views all 1st and 2nd class as just costumers, then you get a queue with Poisson(a1+a2) arrival and Poisson(1) (An M/M/1 queue) and the stationary distribution of the total number of costumers in the queue is Geometric (with parameter 1-a1-a2).
One can also just look at 1st class costumers, and their behavior completely disregards the existence of 2nd class ones. Thus Q1 is a simple M/M/1 queue and has Geometric(1-a1) distribution.
One can write the balance equations, but I do not know how to approach solving or guessing a solution.

Any additional partial information will be helpful.

Comment: Did you run across this , https://www.kobo.com/gb/en/ebook/random-walks-in-the-quarter-plane  ?  I was looking for one of  Malshev's papers from many years ago and could not find it.  I  expect, but don't know, that the books cover the same material.

Comment: Let: $n$ be the number of first class, $m$ the number of second class and $\mu_{nm}$ the stationary measure. Then I think $$\mu_{nm} =\lambda^n \sum_{i=0}^m A_{im} n^i$$ where $\lambda$ is the smaller root of $0=x^2-(a_1+a_2+1)x+a_1$. You can see this if you first solve the balance equations in the $m=0$ case then $m=1$ cases.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt realize that one can get this form by solving the balance equations one layer at a time. I will see how far this can get me. Also thanks for the book recommendation. I just managed to get it.